# Wordpress: You are not allowed to edit this post (even tough I am admin)

Tags: php, database, wordpress

When trying to create or edit posts in wordpress, the error message **"You are not allowed to edit this post"** appears. As mentioned, my user is an administrator. With a different administrator account I still have the same problem.

I first thought the problem might be caused by my wordpress template, so I tried to change it back to one of the default templates but the issues unfortunately still exists.

The second step was to download wordpress, unpack it and replace the wp-config.php with my own wp-config.php to give the new installation access to my old database. After that the problem still existed!

After that I came to the conclusion that the problem can only be inside the database, right? [image: wp_usermeta]
This is a screenshot of SequelPro looking at the `wp_usermeta` table of my wordpress database. Maybe someone knows what could be wrong with this? Where else could there be some misconfigurations that causes this problem?

Thank you! :)

Yours Sincerely, Felix

Comment: There may too many reason for it. May be it's due to cache memory.  You have to Deal with usermeta table for it. Solutions are in these links : 1. [Admin getting "You are not allowed to edit this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-getting-you-are-not-allowed-to-edit-this-post-on-save-draft). && 2. [You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page-1/page/3#post-422005)

Comment: Which user owns your WordPress installation? Does that use have database CRUD privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was that somehow there were no primary keys in my tables. That caused all the trouble I had :/